# Expresion regular con asteriscos pero no consecutivos y con numeros

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito una expresión regular para JavaScript  que detecte este tipo de patrón con un máximo de 6 carácteres:

```
*23456
*234*6
123*5*
123456
```

Pero no puede haber:

```
a*3456
**3456
*12**6
12*4**
ad*32*
*asd*1
```

He intentado muchas maneras pero no consigo el patrón correcto.

Os lo agradecería poder conseguirlo y pueda aprende.

Comment: "He intentado muchas maneras" <--- ¿Cuáles?

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días para hacer regex y probarlos, te recomiendo usar la web https://regex101.com/r/G9vEjl/1. Como no sabía exactamente que condiciones necesitas, me he limitado a escribir una regex para los patrones válidos:

```
^(\*\d{5})|(\*\d{3}\*\d)|(\d{3}\*\d\*)|(\d{6})$
```

Para hacer esto he usado:

1. ^ : indica principio de texto.
2. $ : indica final de texto.
3. () : se usan para agrupar los diferentes casos.
4. \* : Carácter * de forma literal (si lo pones sin la barra significa 0 o más repeticiones)
5. \d : cualquier número
6. {Máximo} : número de rediciones dentro esquema {mínimo, máximo}
7. | : equivalente a un OR

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial!! me viene muy bien, no daba con el algoritmo correcto, te agradezco la información tan detallada.
Yo hacia el algoritmo pero no conseguía separar los dos asteriscos juntos, con lo que me estaba frustrando un poco. Ahora viendo tu respuesta me alegra aprender mas. Muchas gracias